# Yocto Boot Partition error (Intel Edison)

Tags: linux-kernel, u-boot, yocto, intel-edison

I was trying to resize partitions of Intel Edison which runs on Yocto system. I destroyed partition 1 somehow. So when I reboot system it loops forever to boot the system correctly. So, interrupted boot sequence and checked for partitions to see what is wrong. As you can see down below partitions start from number two not one! According to error from bootloader it searches for part 1 but cannot find . So how can I add/ create/ repair manually partition 1 to recover system?

```
boot > printenv partitions

partitions=uuid_disk=${uuid_disk};name=u-boot0,start=1MiB,size=2MiB,uuid=${uuid_uboot0};name=u-boot-env0,size=1MiB,uuid=${uuid_uboot_env0};name=u-boot1,size=2MiB,uuid=${uuid_uboot1};name=u-boot-env1,size=1MiB,uuid=${uuid_uboot_env1};name=factory,size=1MiB,uuid=${uuid_factory};name=panic,size=24MiB,uuid=${uuid_panic};name=boot,size=32MiB,uuid=${uuid_boot};name=rootfs,size=512MiB,uuid=${uuid_rootfs};name=update,size=768MiB,uuid=${uuid_update};name=home,size=-,uuid=${uuid_home};


boot > mmc part


Partition Map for MMC device 0  --   Partition Type: DOS


Part    Start Sector    Num Sectors     UUID            Type
  2     16              7634928         00000000-02     83
```

Boot Sequence

```
******************************
PSH KERNEL VERSION: b0182727
                WR: 20104000
******************************


SCU IPC: 0x800000d0  0xfffce92c


PSH miaHOB version: TNG.B0.VVBD.0000000c


microkernel built 23:15:13 Apr 24 2014


******* PSH loader *******
PCM page cache size = 192 KB
Cache Constraint = 0 Pages
Arming IPC driver ..
Adding page store pool ..
PagestoreAddr(IMR Start Address) = 0x04899000
pageStoreSize(IMR Size)          = 0x00080000


*** Ready to receive application ***




U-Boot 2014.04 (Oct 14 2014 - 15:19:04)


       Watchdog enabled
DRAM:  980.6 MiB
MMC:   tangier_sdhci: 0
In:    serial
Out:   serial
Err:   serial
Hit any key to stop autoboot:  0
Target:blank
Partitioning already done...
Flashing already done...
**dfu_fill_entity_mmc: could not find partition #1 on mmc device #0!
ERROR: DFU entities configuration failed!**


at drivers/dfu/dfu.c:71/dfu_init_env_entities()
dfu - Device Firmware Upgrade


Usage:
dfu <USB_controller> <interface> <dev> [list|timeout]
  - device firmware upgrade via <USB_controller>
    on device <dev>, attached to interface
    <interface>
    [list] - list available alt settings
    [timeout] - specify inactivity timeout in sec, doesn't work whit list
** Invalid partition 7 **
Error: Invalid Boot Flag (found 0xffef, expected 0xaa55)
## Kernel loading failed ...
zboot - Boot bzImage


Usage:
zboot [addr] [size] [initrd addr] [initrd size]
      addr -        The optional starting address of the bzimage.
                    If not set it defaults to the environment
                    variable "fileaddr".
      size -        The optional size of the bzimage. Defaults to
                    zero.
      initrd addr - The address of the initrd image to use, if any.
      initrd size - The size of the initrd image to use, if any.


Unknown boot mode: boot
Saving Environment to MMC...
Writing to MMC(0)... done
Resetting to default boot mode and reboot...
resetting ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved that problem myself. After interrupting boot sequence use gpt command to add new partition to mmc. Then, system boots correctly.

Comment: how did you use the gpt command?